# POST 403 forbiden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy haciendo una web y estaba haciendo la parte de creacion del articulo, todo esto trabajando con Fetch en react, hasta ahora el login del usuario esta perfecto y me devuelve el token. pero ahora cuando quiero crear un articulo y envio el articulo mediante su accion, me devuelve la consola 403 forbiden en las cabeceras estoy enviando la autorizacion con el token. adjunto mi codigo:

```
create: e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const store = getStore();
            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(store.createPost),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `key: ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
                }
            }).then(resp => {
                console.log("status code post ", resp.status);
                return resp.json();
            });

            console.log("create");
        }
```

Comment: No uso react, pero están bien esos headers? `Authorization` está sin comillas y la `key` tiene comillas diagonales.

Comment: Estás corriendo ese api en tu máquina. Quizá sea más fácil averiguar el error desde el backend.

Comment: @azeós probe los headers con comillas y nada

Comment: @Osuka42  si solo estoy probando la api en local para ver que todo este bien con el front.